# Button control as ListView DataTemplate container wrt Drag-and-Drop of ListView Elements

Tags: xaml, listview, drag-and-drop, uwp, winrt-xaml

When I use a Button control in DataTemplate for ListView (UWP app), Drag-and-Drop of ListView items doesn't work. If I use containers like StackPanel, RelativePanel or Grid, instead of Button control, everything works fine. I would prefer the Button control as a container, because I like its mouse Hover effect on ListView items. I can do something similar for StackPanel, etc, with a custom hover effect by using a combination of Style and Behavior programming but trying to avoid this route (too involved).

Can I do something to the Button control so that it gives me the hover and also responds to the Drag-and-Drop event when part of a ListView DataTemplate?

I am also curious what specifically makes the Button suppress the Drag-and-Drop of ListView items.

Comment: You should consider restyling listview item for a customized hover effect than using a Button here, which will swallow all your gestures like drag n drop. Just need to make sure to test the virtualization performance; or, as you are already aware, do a custom one within your stack panel.

Comment: I have to reconsider that option. I started off with restyling the listview and while it has everything I need including hover, for what I needed  it wasn't as flexible as using a custom container like a button control (implementing different configurations within a listview items array). Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The Button is capturing the pointer which cause the pointer click event not be bubble up to the ListViewItem which cause the Drag&Drop to start.

You can take a look at `ReleasePointerCapture` method which will release the pointer capture allowing other item to capture it.

You will need to create a new class which extends the default Button class and override for example the `OnPointerPressed` method to choose the logic between the drag&drop and the click on the button.